# Wrong facebook preview published on timeline

Tags: facebook-like

In this page: http://www.rockit.it/dimartino/concerti I've a Facebook Like button. This used to work. It was working ok for many monthes.
Now it doesn't work properly, this is what happens: when I click on the like button the facebook dialog to post comment on my timeline opens ok. But when I publish the content to the timeline the preview is wrong. Instead of the descriptions appear a "Link Link Link Link" text.
The https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug tool doesn't show any error.

When posting everything seem ok:
[image: like button dialog problem]

But the preview in timeline is wrong:
[image]

Do you know how to fix this problem? Can't find nothing for my "Link Link Link Link" facebook problem.

Comment: really? anyone who see Link Link Link Link on his timeline?