# Facebook: Link preview before posting does not match preview after posting

Tags: facebook, facebook-sharer, facebook-share

I have a link to a page on my website.  I've recently changed the open graph image and description for that page.  I've called the Facebook Graph API to re-scrape my page and this API call returns with an HTTP status code of 200.  The Facebook Sharing Debugger correctly shows the new image and new description:
[image]

When I then attempt to share this page on Facebook the link preview before posting correctly shows the new image and description:
[image]

However, when I then view the post on Facebook, the old image and description still appears:
[image]

Has anyone else encountered this before and found a satisfactory work around?  Is this a Facebook bug?

This behavior appears to mirror the behavior in these SO questions, however neither of these questions have particularly satisfactory answers:

- [Wrong facebook preview published on timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14361848/wrong-facebook-preview-published-on-timeline)
- [Open Graph Object Debugger does not match Facebook Share from site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29088543/open-graph-object-debugger-does-not-match-facebook-share-from-site)

Comment: Can you post the URL here, please? (Not going to type that off of a secreenshot.)

Comment: I'm reluctant to add that to the question since the lifetime of this question is going to be longer than the lifetime of my particular link in question.  (The link is to a page on an ephemeral test environment.)  How would having the URL facilitate answering the question?